# Unable to route request using flask blueprints

Tags: python, flask

Below is the structure of of myapplication directory:

```
|`-- mymodules
    |-- config.py
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- views.py
    |-- mod_stock
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- static
    |   |-- templates
    |   `-- views.py
```

Below is code in mod_stock/views.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint

stockBlueprint = Blueprint('stock', 
                       __name__,
                       template_folder = 'templates',
                       static_folder = 'static')

@stockBlueprint.route("/getStock",methods=['GET'])
def getStock():
    return "stock value"
```

Below is the code in mod_stock/**init**.py:

```
from . import views
```

Code in mymodules/views.py:

```
from mymodules import mainBlueprint

@mainBlueprint.route("/")
def gethomepage():
    return "homepage"
```

Code in mymodules/**init**.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, Flask
from config import Config

application = Flask(__name__)
application.config.from_object(Config)

mainBlueprint = Blueprint('main',__name__)

from views import *

from .mod_stock.views import stockBlueprint
application.register_blueprint(mainBlueprint)
application.register_blueprint(stockBlueprint)
```

I can see that the routes are registered in application.url_map. However, when I do either curl localhost:5000 or curl localhost:5000/getStock, I am getting a 404 error. So what should I do to fix it?

Under myapplication/ I've main.py which imports application from mymodules and runs it.

EDIT : Below is the code:

```
from mymodules import application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, use_reloader=False,   debug=True)
```

Comment: There's no `run` in any of your codes.

Comment: I added just a comment mentioning how I am running the application. I've edited my post to show the relevant code.